# find a value $n_0$, that depends on $w$ such that $X_n(w)=0$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let:
$$
X_n(w) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{for $ 0\le w \le \frac {n+1}{2n}$ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise } \\
\end{cases}
$$

For $ 1/2< w \le1$ I  need to find a value $n_0$, that depends on $w$ such that
$\label{} X_n(w)=0, \qquad \textrm{ for all }n>n_0$.

The answer should be $n_0=\frac{1}{2w-1}$. But how do I get that? Thank you..

Comment: you can get this result by doing $\frac{n_0+1}{2n_0} = w$, i.e. $X_{n_0}(w) = 1$ but $X_n(w) = 0$ for any $n>n_0$.

Comment: Thank you very much